# XCode project stopped working and has a bunch of weird errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was changing some stuff around in my app and tried to re-run it and all of a sudden I get a ton of errors in the console that don't really make any sense. Does anyone know what's going on here? How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: what I changed isn't what's causing the error - I literally just moved a line from one function to another

Comment: which xcode you are using ?

Comment: I'm using XCode 11.4.1

Comment: using cocoa pod ?

Comment: Yep, I'm using cocoa pods

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Restart XCode... it had to install some stuff so that it could run. *sigh*